# Problem with running android project after updating

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
[2010-12-17 07:37:12 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read /Users/macuser/android-sdk-mac/AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/macuser/android-sdk-mac/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does the file exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to create a new folder by name platforms tools and fill the contents of tools inside this folder .. this issue happens when we are updating from 2.2 to 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Please, ensure you haven't accidentally deleted your manifest file.